# Apache: How to add name based apache virtual host without breaking default behavior of [ip]:[port]

Tags: apache

(Warning: I'm totally new at customizing Apache...)

Scenario: I'm setting up a DD-WRT LAN and hosting a website, running on my laptop, that I want others on the wifi connection to be able to visit.

**Needs:**

- http://cutename.website   should go to localhost:8080
- I need the static LAN ip of my laptop, 198.168.1.111 to behave in a "default" fashion, where http://198.168.1.111 goes to my localhost or, say, 198.168.1.111:6020 would go to localhost:6020

**Problem:**

When I set up apache like so:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName cutename.website
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/

</VirtualHost>
```

This makes cutename.website go to localhost:8080 as I want, but now 198.168.1.111 or 198.168.1.111:6020 doesn't work as before, instead,   198.168.1.111 goes to localhost:8080 and 198.168.1.111:6020 doesn't connect.  I understand that apache will match the first virtualhost if there is no match, which is *not* what I want.

How do I set up vhosts/apache to not break the default [ip]:[port] routing/behavior?  Or, how can I only use vhosts for matching cutename.website but ignore everything else?

Comment: You can define two different blocks instead of one wild-card block with * :
<VirtualHost cutename.website:80> AND <VirtualHost 198.168.1.111:80>.
It can be still a bit difficult to get it running especially as IP and domains are mixed then but it's possible, so report any errors and problems to get more detailed help.

Comment: specify the `<VirtualHost _default_>` or place that `VirtualHost` on the last position. The `NameVirtualHost` is  Apache v2.3.11-

Comment: @Deadooshka What would I specify inside `<VirtualHost _default_>`  .  What settings here would say "don't do anything, or just pass through"?

Comment: empty `VirtualHost` means global options Inheritance